# Connection.Refresh causes query to refresh twice in VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, powerquery

I am refreshing a power query in my VBA code. The query uses a dynamic file path variable from a cell value in my Excel workbook. The dynamic file path points to a text file that contains the query I want to run. The steps in the code are:

1. Create a query in the Excel workbook and write it into a text file.
2. Refresh the connections in the workbook.

The specific query that is giving me problems is when I run an INSERT query to insert rows into a table. Each row I want to submit is duplicated. This would indicate to me that the query refreshed twice. What can I do to fix this?

I tried setting the BackgroundQuery property to false in the code. Did not work. I tried several things, and later there were three of each row being added to my table. The text files I am referencing are stored on OneDrive. Could this be causing the issue?

Comment: Did this answer work for you? If so please toggle checkmark next to answer to mark issue solved

Answer (score 0):

What is your code?  If this was your powerquery code, it would read from an external file specified in range **rangename** and execute it

```
let  filename= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="rangename"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],                                    
Source = Text.FromBinary(File.Contents(filename)),
EvaluatedExpression = Expression.Evaluate(Source, #shared)
in EvaluatedExpression
```

where **rangename** contains **C:\PowerQueryQueries\DynamicQuery.txt**